# Horizontal placement of graphic in left and right margins

Tags: graphics, positioning, margins, marginpar, marginnote

I want to place small graphics in the outer margins of my 2-sided document. I've been using, e.g.,

```
\marginpar[{\hfill
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{figures/ivy-univ.png}\hspace{8 pt}
}]{
\includegraphics[scale=.3]{figures/ivy-univ.png}
}
```

It works fine on the right-hand page margins, but the graphic overlaps the text on the left-hand pages.  I've been playing with the `\hfill`, `\hspace` and with using `\marginnote`, but can't get it right. `\marginnote` got the position right, but didn't recognize left vs right page properly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you get overfull `\hbox` warnings? Maybe the graphics is too large for the margin?

Comment: use width=\marginparparwidth rather than scale=.3 then it will not be too large for the space